# Looping through AJAX result and post to HTML,

Tags: mysql, ajax, for-loop

I have the following AJAX code for processing a returned results from the database,

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  async: true,
  url: "../../../avocado/private/functions/measures.php",
  data: {name:selectedValue},
  success: function(data, status){
      var selectedData = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(selectedData);
      document.getElementById("measures").innerHTML    = "<div id=\"measures\">"
                                                       + "<table class=\"table table-condensed\">"
                                                       + "<tr><th>desc1</th><td>"+selectedData[0][6]+"</td></tr>"
                                                       + "<tr><th>desc2</th><td>"+selectedData[0][7]+"</td></tr>"
                                                       + "<tr><th>desc3</th><td>"+selectedData[0][8]+"</td></tr>"
                                                       + "<tr><th>desc4</th><td>"+selectedData[0][9]+"</td></tr>"
                                                       + "</table>"
                                                       + "</div>";

  },
  error: function(xhr, status, err) {
    alert(status + ": " + err);
  }
});
```

The data returned is a 2D array, like this below,

```
Array[5]
0: Array[14]
1: Array[14]
2: Array[14]
3: Array[14]
4: Array[14]
```

so what I want to do is to loop each array and display the inner information on the HTML page but I have no idea how I should go about doing it.. this code only returns the values stored on index[0].

Can I please get some help?

==============================================================================

## UPDATED

So I tried to use Jquery.append() like the following below..

```
 jQuery.each( selectedData, function( i, val ) {
          $("measures").append(  
            "<table class=\"table table-condensed\">"
            + "<tr><th>desc1</th><td>"+selectedData[i][6]+"</td></tr>"
            + "<tr><th>desc2</th><td>"+selectedData[i][7]+"</td></tr>"
            + "<tr><th>desc3</th><td>"+selectedData[i][8]+"</td></tr>"
            + "<tr><th>desc4</th><td>"+selectedData[i][9]+"</td></tr>"
            + "</table>"
          );
       });
      /*
      document.getElementById("measures").innerHTML    = "<div id=\"measures\">"
                                                       + "<table class=\"table table-condensed\">"
                                                       + "<tr><th>desc1</th><td>"+selectedData[0][6]+"</td></tr>"
                                                       + "<tr><th>desc2</th><td>"+selectedData[0][7]+"</td></tr>"
                                                       + "<tr><th>desc3</th><td>"+selectedData[0][8]+"</td></tr>"
                                                       + "<tr><th>desc4</th><td>"+selectedData[0][9]+"</td></tr>"
                                                       + "</table>"
                                                       + "</div>";
        */
```

now..its not appending any values to the div #measures at all...

Comment: By value stored on index[0] you mean that you are getting the data from first array. right ?

Comment: Then to access you should change the index value form 0 to another no. i.e. selectedData[1][6] will return data from second array.

Comment: Also, If you want to loop the array you can use 2 for loops (nested) to go through all the values in array

Comment: but the problem is that I don't know how many elements are in the array, so I can't just manually type all that.

Comment: You can go through the following link: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/ It has nice examples of how you can go through array

Comment: If I decide to use for loop the problem is that each for loop will replace the previously appended result so I'm only getting the last element in the array appended in the HTML..there must be a way but I don't know..hence Im asking..

Comment: Yo can use .append() instead of .innerHTML(). This will append the new element

Comment: I tried to use the append().. with no success..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tried the code. But I hope this will help you.

```
document.getElementById("measures").innerHTML    = "<div id=\"measures\">";
$.each( selectedData, function( index, value ){
  $.each( index, function( index2, value2 ){
     $('#measures').append(value2);
  });  
});
```